# How to iterate over a list of floating point numbers in this code

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import math 
codebook_init= [[15,15,15,15],

[47 ,47, 47, 47],

[79 ,79 ,79, 79],

[112, 112, 112 ,112],

[146 ,146, 146, 146],

[178 ,178 ,178, 178],

[210, 210 ,210, 210],

[242, 242 ,242, 242]] 

tr =[[139,144,149,153,155,155,155,155],
    [144,151,153,156,159,156,156,156],
    [150,155,160,163,158,156,156,156],
    [159,161,162,160,160,159,159,159],
    [159,160,161,162,162,155,155,155],
    [161,161,161,161,160,157,157,157],
    [162,162,161,163,162,157,157,157],
    [162,162,161,161,163,158,158,158]]

new_set= [[tr[0][0],tr[0][1],tr[1][0],tr[1][1]],
          [tr[0][2],tr[0][3],tr[1][2],tr[1][3]],
          [tr[0][4],tr[0][5],tr[1][4],tr[1][5]],
          [tr[0][6],tr[0][7],tr[1][6],tr[1][7]],
          [tr[2][0],tr[2][1],tr[3][0],tr[3][1]],
          [tr[2][2],tr[2][3],tr[3][1],tr[3][3]],
          [tr[2][4],tr[2][5],tr[3][4],tr[3][5]],
          [tr[2][6],tr[2][7],tr[3][6],tr[3][7]],
          [tr[4][0],tr[4][1],tr[5][0],tr[5][1]],
          [tr[4][2],tr[4][3],tr[5][2],tr[5][3]],
          [tr[4][4],tr[4][5],tr[5][4],tr[5][5]],
          [tr[4][6],tr[4][7],tr[5][6],tr[5][7]],
          [tr[6][0],tr[6][1],tr[7][0],tr[7][1]],
          [tr[6][2],tr[6][3],tr[7][2],tr[7][3]],
          [tr[6][4],tr[6][5],tr[7][4],tr[7][5]],
          [tr[6][6],tr[6][7],tr[7][6],tr[7][7]],]

print(*new_set, sep= "\n")

def euclidean_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(row1)-1):
        distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
    return math.sqrt(distance)




      
eu_dist15 = []
eu_dist47=[]
eu_dist79=[]
eu_dist112=[]
eu_dist146=[]
eu_dist178=[]
eu_dist210=[]
eu_dist242=[]


row15=codebook_init[0]  
row47=codebook_init[1] 
row79=codebook_init[2] 
row112=codebook_init[3] 
row146=codebook_init[4] 
row178=codebook_init[5] 
row210=codebook_init[6]  
row242=codebook_init[7] 

for i in new_set:

        eu_dist15= euclidean_distance(row15, i)
        print (eu_dist15)

for i in eu_dist15:
     print(i)
```

#In the above code i am trying to create a codebook for vector quantization. First I'm trying to calculate the Euclidean distance and then trying to get the minimal value to update the code book with new set.

While doing it im facing an issue saying that the float type is not iterable and the error happens exactly in this "for i in eu_dist15:  print(i)"  part.

Comment: I can't help you with the "vector quantization" as I don't have the background, but I can tell you your `for i in new_set:` is not doing what you expect. As it is now, it is rewriting eu_dis15 as a single float, and that is why you can't iterate over it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your `eu_dist15` is a distance not a list of distance. If you want to get all the distances and get the minimum out of them then:

```
...
row15=codebook_init[0]  
row47=codebook_init[1] 
row79=codebook_init[2] 
row112=codebook_init[3] 
row146=codebook_init[4] 
row178=codebook_init[5] 
row210=codebook_init[6]  
row242=codebook_init[7] 

distances = []

for i in new_set:
  # calculate euclidean distance
  eu_dist15= euclidean_distance(row15, i)
  # store distance in to a list
  distances.append(eu_dist15)
# Get the min to update code book
minimum = min(distances)
print(minimum)
```